# InflateException for Android Map on some devices

Tags: android, dictionary, android-inflate

So I have this one app in the Play Store with few thausands of downloads and I guess some of them are happy users as well. App is strongly based on Google Maps V2. Everything works fine except I've noticed few exceptions with affected 4 users in total (in last 30 days). There seems to be some kind of issue with inflating the Google Map but I cannot get any info from the log itself.

Here is my crashlytics full log for those users:

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.*packageid*/com.*packageid*.views.map.MapActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #16: Error inflating class fragment
       at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2187)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2236)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:138)
       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1199)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5102)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Method.java)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:602)
       at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(NativeStart.java)
Caused by android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #16: Error inflating class fragment
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:713)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:758)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.parseInclude(LayoutInflater.java:839)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:745)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353)
       at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:276)
       at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:136)
       at com.parkanizer.parkingapp.views.map.MapActivity.onCreate(MapActivity.java:106)
       at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
       at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2151)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2236)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:138)
       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1199)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5102)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Method.java)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:602)
       at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(NativeStart.java)
Caused by java.lang.NullPointerException
       at maps.G.a.a(Unknown Source)
       at maps.V.N.a(Unknown Source)
       at maps.D.e.a(Unknown Source)
       at maps.D.p.a(Unknown Source)
       at maps.ad.ae.a(Unknown Source)
       at maps.ad.t.a(Unknown Source)
       at maps.ad.M.a(Unknown Source:2000)
       at uy.onTransact(:com.google.android.gms.DynamiteModulesB:107)
       at android.os.Binder.transact(Binder.java:361)
       at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.IMapFragmentDelegate$zza$zza.onCreateView(Unknown Source)
       at com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment$zza.onCreateView(Unknown Source)
       at com.google.android.gms.dynamic.zza$4.zzb(Unknown Source)
       at com.google.android.gms.dynamic.zza.zza(Unknown Source)
       at com.google.android.gms.dynamic.zza.onCreateView(Unknown Source)
       at com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment.onCreateView(Unknown Source)
       at com.parkanizer.parkingapp.views.MySupportMapFragment.onCreateView(MySupportMapFragment.java:18)
       at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1974)
       at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1036)
       at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1230)
       at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.addFragment(FragmentManager.java:1332)
       at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.onCreateView(FragmentManager.java:2288)
       at android.support.v4.app.FragmentController.onCreateView(FragmentController.java:120)
       at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.dispatchFragmentsOnCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:357)
       at android.support.v4.app.BaseFragmentActivityHoneycomb.onCreateView(BaseFragmentActivityHoneycomb.java:31)
       at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:80)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:689)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:758)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.parseInclude(LayoutInflater.java:839)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:745)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353)
       at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:276)
       at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:136)
       at com.parkanizer.parkingapp.views.map.MapActivity.onCreate(MapActivity.java:106)
       at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
       at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2151)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2236)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:138)
       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1199)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5102)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Method.java)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:602)
```

Here is my XML file for the view. There is really nothing special going on, and for most of the cases users are crash-free.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/content_map"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <fragment
            android:id="@+id/map"
            tools:visibility="gone"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            map:cameraTargetLat="50.2633971"
            map:cameraTargetLng="19.0111041"
            map:cameraZoom="10"
            class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment" />

<... Some other typical UI elements ...>
```

I wans't able to fix my problem, also to reproduce it. Do you have any ideas?

In fabric, there is total of 33 crashes with affected 4 users. 88% of the crashes is for strange kind of device "Lechpol", the rest is samsung (GT-I9300)

[image]

All of them running on Android 4.4.

Do you guys have any idea what could cause the crash? Any advices appreciated.

EDIT: after further research I found the device that has so many crashes, this is it:
https://www.ox.ee/en/product/836741

Answer (score 0):

set visibility gone/visible for relative layout

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/content_map"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:visibility="gone"  >
<fragment 
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/map"
        tools:context=".MapsActivity"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment" />

 </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Why exactly should it help...?

Comment: I too had this issue.It has got to do something with the hardware difference in different devices

Comment: I am not 100% sur but its qorth a try

Comment: According to usage, the fragment is only used by setRetainInstance and getMap. I'm not 100% on how they work but as far as I can tell there's nothing there that controls view visibility.

Answer (score 0):

```
<activity android:name="com.bison.activities.YourActivity"
            android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
            >
            <intent-filter>
                <action
                    android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
```

Try adding this to you activity in manifest. If it helps study the hardware acceleration in google documentation

Comment: Ye i got android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY" if it's what you are asking. I think without this tag the error log would look completely different.